# KeeWeb Desktop Install Error

Tags: linux, package, deb, dpkg

i just installed Ubuntu Gnome 16.04 LTS and i'm trying to install KeeWeb which worked on my Elementary OS... i downloaded newest version of KeeWeb Desktop for Linux (.deb package) and i get error... i looked it up in google but i didn't find anything usefull... can you guys help? Please :)

```
(Reading database ... 191047 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack KeeWeb.linux.x64.deb ...
Unpacking keeweb-desktop (1.2.2-1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive KeeWeb.linux.x64.deb (--install):
 unable to create '/opt/keeweb-desktop/content_shell.pak.dpkg-new' (while processing './opt/keeweb-desktop/content_shell.pak'): No such file or directory
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 KeeWeb.linux.x64.deb
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same problem for me.
Execute:

```
sudo mkdir /opt/keeweb-desktop
sudo chmod 777 /opt/keeweb-desktop
```

Then run the installer again.